# Android Universal Image Loader Mark has been invalidated

Tags: android, gridview, jpeg, universal-image-loader, xoom

I have images displayed with Universal Image Loader. They are downloaded from a web directory and shown in a Gridview. Seems to be working great except if the pictures were originally sent from a Xoom tablet.  Pictures are .jpg average of 180kb. I am sure there are more devices besides the Xoom doing this but I can't figure out why.  The picture won't display and gives me an input/output error toast.  My logcat shows this

```
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376): Mark has been invalidated.
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376): java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:350)
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.defineImageSizeAndRotation(BaseImageDecoder.java:88)
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:69)
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:305)
11-02 14:32:48.840: E/ImageLoader(2376):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:260)
```

My imageloader code in onCreate is

```
imgLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_empty).build();

    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions).build();

    imgLoader.init(config);
```

And finally for displaying the images

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(albumdisplay.this);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imgLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

I just don't understand why it can display one .jpg and not another.  The images in question display correctly when viewed on a webpage. Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) ?

Comment: I had it set as RGB_8888 but changing it didn't seem to make a difference.